# Rails Active Record: SQL Expression In Update Statement

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

How can you execute the following SQL statement using AR:

```
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance + 100 WHERE id = 1
```

I tried to find ways to execute SQL expressions in AR update statements, but nothing is working. I can *not* do something like

```
account.update balance: account.balance + 100
```

Because that would open all sort of race condition issues. The DBMS is the proper entity to handle this kind of update.

Any idea how to write it using AR?

I realize this can be done using:

```
Account.where(id: 1).update_all("balance = balance + 100")
```

But this looks very *un-rails* like to me. I was hoping for a cleaner solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
account.increment :balance, 100
```

[`increment`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-increment) is the documentation.

Comment: thanks, but what if I want to do something like ```balance = old_balance + amount```? (both "old_balance" and "amount" are fields in the table)

Comment: @Faisal humm.. To meet the comment using AR, `#update_all` is the way to go.